# How to get elements from a dataframe given dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a list of dates in a dataframe, and another dataframe containing percentage changes throughout a day.

Sample dataframe with dates (`df_date`):

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
'Specific_date': {0: '2016-01-10', 1: '2016-01-12', 2: '2016-01-13', 3: '2016-01-19'}})

df_test['Specific_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['Specific_date'])
```

Percentage change dataframe (`df_percent`):

```
Hour        9am     10am    11am    12pm    1pm     2pm     3pm     4pm
Date                                
2016-01-05  20.6475 20.5900 20.4225 20.6275 20.1600 19.6500 19.6250 19.4100
2016-01-06  21.3550 20.8675 20.6100 20.6525 20.8900 21.0125 21.0600 20.5125
2016-01-07  23.0075 22.7975 23.0050 23.5975 24.4675 25.2450 25.1600 24.9575
2016-01-08  22.9125 23.2400 23.8575 23.9475 24.0425 24.4000 25.7950 26.7625
2016-01-11  25.7500 25.9100 25.8800 25.9325 26.7650 26.4025 24.9425 24.2725
2016-01-12  22.5500 22.6900 23.2700 23.2550 23.1425 22.8175 22.2925 22.4175
2016-01-13  21.8175 22.6200 22.5225 23.2675 23.9650 25.0500 24.9575 25.1100
2016-01-14  25.4600 25.0050 24.2875 24.2050 24.2850 23.7800 23.6775 23.9575
2016-01-15  28.3200 28.5925 27.8400 28.8900 29.2925 28.4225 27.6525 27.1525
2016-01-19  26.1625 26.3400 26.0725 26.2550 26.3275 26.9225 26.5725 26.0075
```

I am trying to use those dates in `df_test` to filter out dates in the sample dataframe (data runs from 2016 to 2020 daily).

Logic: I want to get the value at the date (T=0) in `df_date`, along with the values at dates 3, 2, and 1 day before (T-3, T-2, T-1), and 1, 2, and 3, days after. (T+1, T+2, T+3), append them to a new dataframe, and check for the next date in the dictionary to append associated values to those dataframes.

I had thought about trying to create a new dataframe for each T, and assuming I would do that, the pseudo-logic-english-code-whatever would look like this.

```
Tm3, Tm2, Tm1, T0, Tp1, Tp2, Tp3 = pd.DataFrame()
for date in df_percent['Date']:
   if df_percent['Date'] is in df_date['Specific_date']:
       Tm3 = df_percent['Date'] - BDay(3)
       Tm2 = df_percent['Date'] - BDay(2)
       Tm1 = df_percent['Date'] - BDay(1)
       T0 = df_percent['Date']
       Tp1 = df_percent['Date'] + BDay(1)
       Tp2 = df_percent['Date'] + BDay(2)
       Tp3 = df_percent['Date'] + BDay(3)
```

I don't believe this is the right approach, or I'm using the wrong logic, but I cannot yield anything productive from what I have right now with is a Frankenstein version of what I have above.

Expected output sample for Tm3 dataframe for elements in `df_test`:

```
Hour        9am     10am    11am    12pm    1pm     2pm     3pm     4pm
Date
2016-01-06  21.3550 20.8675 20.6100 20.6525 20.8900 21.0125 21.0600 20.5125
2016-01-07  23.0075 22.7975 23.0050 23.5975 24.4675 25.2450 25.1600 24.9575
2016-01-08  22.9125 23.2400 23.8575 23.9475 24.0425 24.4000 25.7950 26.7625
2016-01-13  21.8175 22.6200 22.5225 23.2675 23.9650 25.0500 24.9575 25.1100
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDITED: [image: Error I was receiving from code implementation]

EDIT #2: [image: Second edit of errors]

EDIT #3: [image: Dataframe that might be causing issues.]

EDIT #4: [image: Dataframe incorrectly displaying]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like financial market data. Financial markets are not open every business days (there are trading floor holidays) so you cannot use `BDay`. Instead, it's better to label every day in your `df_percent` sequentially, so that Day 0 is 2016-01-05, day 1 is 2016-01-06, etc. This way you can easily reference n trading days before or after.

```py
# Assign a sequential number to each trading day
df_melt_test_percent = df_melt_test_percent.sort_index().assign(DayNumber=lambda x: range(len(x)))

# Find the indices of the FOMC_dates
tmp = pd.merge(
    df_FOMC_dates, df_melt_test_percent[['DayNumber']],
    left_on='FOMC_dates', right_index=True
)

# For each row, get the FOMC_dates ± 3 days
tmp['delta'] = tmp.apply(lambda _: range(-3, 4), axis=1)

tmp = tmp.explode('delta')
tmp['DayNumber'] += tmp['delta']

# Assemble the result
result = pd.merge(tmp, df_melt_test_percent, on='DayNumber')
```

Result:

```
FOMC_dates DayNumber delta     9am    10am    11am    12pm     1pm     2pm     3pm     4pm
2016-01-12         2    -3 23.0075 22.7975 23.0050 23.5975 24.4675 25.2450 25.1600 24.9575
2016-01-12         3    -2 22.9125 23.2400 23.8575 23.9475 24.0425 24.4000 25.7950 26.7625
2016-01-13         3    -3 22.9125 23.2400 23.8575 23.9475 24.0425 24.4000 25.7950 26.7625
2016-01-12         4    -1 25.7500 25.9100 25.8800 25.9325 26.7650 26.4025 24.9425 24.2725
2016-01-13         4    -2 25.7500 25.9100 25.8800 25.9325 26.7650 26.4025 24.9425 24.2725
2016-01-12         5     0 22.5500 22.6900 23.2700 23.2550 23.1425 22.8175 22.2925 22.4175
2016-01-13         5    -1 22.5500 22.6900 23.2700 23.2550 23.1425 22.8175 22.2925 22.4175
2016-01-12         6     1 21.8175 22.6200 22.5225 23.2675 23.9650 25.0500 24.9575 25.1100
2016-01-13         6     0 21.8175 22.6200 22.5225 23.2675 23.9650 25.0500 24.9575 25.1100
2016-01-19         6    -3 21.8175 22.6200 22.5225 23.2675 23.9650 25.0500 24.9575 25.1100
2016-01-12         7     2 25.4600 25.0050 24.2875 24.2050 24.2850 23.7800 23.6775 23.9575
2016-01-13         7     1 25.4600 25.0050 24.2875 24.2050 24.2850 23.7800 23.6775 23.9575
2016-01-19         7    -2 25.4600 25.0050 24.2875 24.2050 24.2850 23.7800 23.6775 23.9575
2016-01-12         8     3 28.3200 28.5925 27.8400 28.8900 29.2925 28.4225 27.6525 27.1525
2016-01-13         8     2 28.3200 28.5925 27.8400 28.8900 29.2925 28.4225 27.6525 27.1525
2016-01-19         8    -1 28.3200 28.5925 27.8400 28.8900 29.2925 28.4225 27.6525 27.1525
2016-01-13         9     3 26.1625 26.3400 26.0725 26.2550 26.3275 26.9225 26.5725 26.0075
2016-01-19         9     0 26.1625 26.3400 26.0725 26.2550 26.3275 26.9225 26.5725 26.0075
```

Rows with `delta = 0` are your original `FOMC_dates`. You can drop the columns you don't want and pivot it to your preferred shape.

Comment: Hi, first off, thank you so much for the explanation! I'm having a tough time trying to implement it, though, and receiving an error of: `ValueError: cannot insert level_0, already exists` from the `reset_index()` function. I tried `drop = True` and `droplevel(0)` but it didn't change any output.

Comment: Reinitalize the percentage data frame and change to `reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Error posted in OP

Comment: I might have found the problem. Date columns in `df_percent` are not actual column names since they're cast as `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: Posted a sample of the dataframe. Not sure how to convert those columns back, though, since they're just labels.

Comment: I’m charging you extra rep points for making me get out of bed. But now that I’m seeing the real data frame, I’ll update my code

Comment: Edited my answer and also make it clearer. Reinitialize `df_melt_test_percent`

Comment: Maybe the best explanation I've ever received for code help; sincerely, thank you.

Comment: I hate to bother you again since you were so nice about it last night, but now I'm having a problem with displaying the dataframe. I have edited the OP

Comment: Actually it's a bug in the code. I've updated the answer

Comment: Receiving error of `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int32 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` from `tmp = pd.merge` line.

Comment: Hm... I'm turning this into a mess. Can you make a new question and I will try to help you there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954776/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-receiving-value-error-of-merging-object-and-int

Link to new thread.